# Wordpress add_rewrite_rule second argument not working

Tags: wordpress

I am trying to use add_rewrite_rule() to solve a pagination problem I am having. After a lot of research I know the answer. But it seems the second argument of add_rewrite_rule() is never working.

```
add_action( 'init', 'add_category_base_rewrite_rule' );
function add_category_base_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule(
    'publicacoes/(.+?)/page/?([0-9]{1,})/?$',
    'index.php?post_type=artigo&category_name=$matches[1]&paged=$matches[2]',
    'top' 
  );
}
```

I am using the plugin [Debug This](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-this/) to check the rewrite rules

[Debug This return](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSjFa.png)

As you can see the second argument doesn't match what I put in my function. And no matter what I do it doesn't work.

I know the function is being called because it put my rule on the top.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Did you refresh permalink rules, either via function or via settings -> permalinks -> save?

Comment: Yes I did. I put flush_rewrite_rules(true); right before add_action( 'init', 'add_category_base_rewrite_rule' );. And I tried to do it manually as well.